# Describe the elementary row operations to get from one matrix to the other.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Describe a sequence of 3 elementary row operations to get from the first matrix to the second matrix.

$\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 3 \\ 2 & 0 & 1 \\ -5 & 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

So for the first row operation I said to switch row 1 and row 2. For the second row operation I said to take $\frac 1 2$ of row 2. I'm just confused what the last row operation should be. Right now I have the first two rows correct but I need to adjust the third row.

Answer (score 1):

Let the third operation be to subtract three times the second row from the third row.

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to figure out the row operation easily. If its not basic subtraction or addition I don't seem to realize right away or will it just take practice?

Comment: I don't really know. What I did was to think "Row one and two are good, now how wrong is the third row?", then I subtracted the third row you wanted from the third row you had, and lo and behold, it came out to be exactly $3$ times the second row.

Answer (score 0):

Try subtracting $3 \times \text{Row 2}$ from $\text{Row 3}$.